# how to fix path problem with grpc, go and protoc

Tags: go, grpc, proto, protoc

is there any fix fro running protoc command for go outside go path. Like I have to export path for every new project...

`$ export PATH="$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin"`

Comment: `protoc` only needs to be run if your definitions change, so just add this to your dev process i.e. add it to a "code gen" script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just needed to add this to the .zshrc or .bashrc file